# What would be logged as the destination for an emergency landing in a field?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

When logging flights you have a departure point and an arrival point, how would you log the arrival point if you were to have to perform an emergency off field landing in a field or on an interstate?

Comment: I'd say lat/long, but that's only a guess.

Comment: However you want.

Answer (score 5):

I would just write "off fld" in the destination box, if there is one, and describe the location in Remarks.  "Emerg ldng on I-90 2 mi S of Whereverville"  or "Pracaut lndg field 2 mi W of Middleofnowheretown".

You aren't going to get audited over that kind of stuff so don't worry about hyper precision.  If anybody ever looks at your logbook it's just going to be to validate flying times for the purpose of a license or rating.  The other stuff is mostly for your own historical record.

Comment: Yes.  And I have made frequent (non-emergency) landings on dry lakes and such, logged as just "XX lake" or similar.